# Weird problem: sending email from Python fails, but only after(!) some MySQL interaction

Tags: python, mysql, linux, email, smtplib

I'm running into the weirdest of errors. Maybe someone can help?

I have some (very simple) Python code (see below) which does two things:

1. It connects to MySQL (on localhost), does a query, prints the results, then disconnects from MySQL.
2. It sends an email through gmail.

The MySQL portion of the code runs fine.

The weirdness:

- If I remove the MySQL portion of the code, the email-sending portion of the code works just fine.
- If I do not remove the MySQL portion of the code, the email-sending portion of the code raises the following error:

> [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1131)

I'm running Python 3.8 on Linux (Ubuntu 20.04-LTS--kernel version 5.4.0-113-generic)

The MySQL package I installed was mysql-connector-python

Note that I'm using a 'gmail app password' (not the regular gmail password) to login to gmail.

My code (all logins and passwords removed)

```
import mysql.connector
#Connect to MySQL
try:
  mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host = "localhost",
    user = "db_user",
    password = "db_password",
    database = "db_database")
except Exception as err:
  print("\n", "Failed to connect to database", "\n", err)
  exit(1)
print("Connected...")

#Do the query
cur = mydb.cursor()
cur.execute("SHOW DATABASES")
for row in cur:
    print(row[0])

#Disconnect from MySQL
try:
  mydb.disconnect()
except Exception as err:
  print("\n", "Error closing database connection", "\n", err)
  exit(1)
print("Disconnected...")

import smtplib, ssl 
smtp_server = "smtp.gmail.com"
port = 587 
gmail_login = "gmail_login"
gmail_app_password = "gmail_app_password"
gmail_sender = gmail_login + "@gmail.com"
email_receiver = "email_receiver"

message = """\
Subject: Hi there

This message came from Python."""

# Log in to server and send email
try:
  # Create a secure SSL context
  my_context = ssl.create_default_context()
  with smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server, port) as server:
    #server.ehlo()  # Can be omitted
    server.starttls(context = my_context)
    #server.ehlo()  # Can be omitted
    server.login(gmail_login, gmail_app_password)
    server.sendmail(gmail_sender, email_receiver, message)
except Exception as err:
  print("\n", err, "\n")
  exit(1)

exit(0)
```

Comment: What happens if you keep `import mysql.connector` but remove the code that uses MySQL? I suspect something in the MySQL library is changing something related to SSL.

Comment: Great question!! And indeed, leaving only 'import mysql.connector' (removing all MySQL code) but leaving the email code, raises the same SSL error.
Once I remove the 'import mysql.connector' line, the emailing runs fine.

Comment: I've been able to find lots of web pages about solving a problem when that error comes from mysql connector. I can't find anything about it causing problems with other packages.

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with `ssl.create_default_context()`. Something in mysql.connector may be interfering with that.

Comment: I wonder if this might have anything to do with which mysql-connector package to use. I have found 'mysql.connector', 'mysql-connector' and 'mysql-connector-python'.

I'll try uninstalling whichever of these I have, then try them one by one. Maybe that way I can at least find something that works.

Comment: I took the easy way out: separated the MySQL and Email parts in separate programs. With a shell script, run the MySQL part first, then email its results with the email program. Does not answer the question, but works around the problem.